# Trapezoid geometry problem involving areas

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> ABCD is a trapezoid with $AD$ parallel to $BC$. The area of $ABCD$ is $225$. The area of $\triangle BPC$ is $49$. What is the area of $\triangle APD?$

[image: ABCD illustrated]

I can see that the triangles $BPC$ and $APD$ are congruent, though I do not know how to apply this to a solution. The formula for the area of a trapezium doesn't seem to be applicable here.

Could someone provide an explained solution which doesn't involve trigonometric functions?

Comment: I don't know how to explain that (without computations) but if $A$ is the area of the trapezoid and $X$ and $Y$ are the areas of the two triangles in your question, then $\sqrt{A} = \sqrt{X} + \sqrt{Y}$.

Comment: "The formula for the area of a trapezium doesn't seem to be applicable here." It is. Start by normalizing the height of the trapezoid to $1$ to simplify. Introduce $a$ and $b$ the lengths $BC$ and $AD$. Compute the two known areas in function of $a$ and $b$ and solve for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=BC$ and $b=AD$ the bases of the trapezoid, $h_1$, $h_2$ and $h=h_1+h_2$ the heights of $PBC$, $PAD$ and $ABCD$. From the similitude of triangles $PBC$ and $PAD$ we have $h_2/h_1=b/a$, so we may write:
$$
225={1\over2}(a+b)h={1\over2}(a+b)(h_1+h_2)
={1\over2}ah_1\left(1+{b\over a}\right)^2=49\left(1+{b\over a}\right)^2.
$$
From that we gain:
$$
1+{b\over a}={15\over7},
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
{b\over a}={8\over7},
$$
and finally:
$$
\hbox{area of}\ \triangle APD=
\left({b\over a}\right)^2 \hbox{area of}\ \triangle PBC=64.
$$

Comment: Could you explain how ${1\over2}(a+b)(h_1+h_2)
={1\over2}ah_1\left(1+{b\over a}\right)^2?$

Comment: $a+b=a(1+b/a)$ and $h_1+h_2=h_1(1+h_2/h_1)=h_1(1+b/a)$.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but what do you mean by $a + b = a(1+\frac{b}{a})?$ I don't understand where the $1$ or the fraction comes from.

Comment: Just multiply out the RHS and check the result is the same as the LHS.

Comment: It's a bit like collecting a common factor: $a^2+ab=a(a+b)$. Basic algebra.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{S_{\triangle ABP}}{S_{\triangle BCP}} = \frac{AP}{PC} = \frac{DP}{BP} = \frac{S_{\triangle DCP}}{S_{\triangle BCP}} := r$$
(Assume this ratio is $r$.) Then we also have
$$ \frac{S_{\triangle ADP}}{S_{\triangle ABP}} = \frac{DP}{BP} = r.$$
Therefore, 
$$S_{\triangle ABP} = 49r $$
$$S_{\triangle DCP} = 49r $$
$$S_{\triangle ADP} = 49r^2 $$
So
$$ 49 + 49r + 49r+ 49r^2 = 225$$ and $$ r= \frac{8}{7}$$
$$S_{\triangle ADP} = 49r^2 = 64$$

Comment: Boy.... that answer certainly doesn't look correct, based on a visual inspection of the areas in question.  But perhaps it is a visual illusion and the equations are all correct!

Comment: What does $S_{\triangle ABP}$ denote? @DavidG.Stork , the answer is correct if you were wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this question, I've got another answer.

In any quadrilateral $ABCD$, where $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $O$, it is easy to prove that  $|ABO|\cdot |DCO|=|ADO|\cdot |BCO|$ where $|$ denotes area.

In this question, we see that $|ABP|=|DCP|$ - let this area be $y$, and let $|APD|=x$. Then by the above equality, we have that $y^2=49x\implies y=7\sqrt{x}$. Since $|ABCD|=225, x+14\sqrt{x}+49=225$, and so $(\sqrt{x}+7)^2=225$. Hence $\sqrt{x}=8$ and thus $|APD|=64$.